Deleting an httpOnly cookie via route handler in next js app router
I'm trying to remove and httpOnly Cookie that I set on serverSide of my nextjs project ,but when I can't remove it at all. I don't get any errors.
I tried to use route handler so that i can remove it and the code goes like this:
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = request.cookies.get('token')

  if (token) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Welcome back!' })
  }

  const response = NextResponse.json({ message: 'Welcome!' })

  response.cookies.set('token', '', {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 0,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    path: '/'
  })

  return response
}


I logged the response of the route handler and it seems to be working but the cookie is not removed. Anyone has any solutions?

Note that if the cookie was originally set with different attributes (e.g. httpOnly, secure, path), removal may not work.
Also, try adding expires: new Date(0) in the configuration.

@EdoardoCamara thank you for pointing out some of the possible issues, I added the expires props to the options and also checked if the set cookie is not the same , but the token is still there.

I also tries  const token = request.cookies.delete('token') in the route handler but i wouldn't work.

I needed such a route to logout the user and remove an httpOnly cookie. This is working for me in NextJS 15.0.2
/app/user/logout.ts

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = "/";

    const res = NextResponse.redirect(url);
    res.cookies.delete("name_of_the_cookie_that_needs_to_be_removed");

    return res;
}

